# Getting an error when I try the Python wrapper for Stanford OpenIE

Tags: python, windows, stanford-nlp, triples

I am trying to run the wrapper given [here](https://github.com/philipperemy/stanford-openie-python). However, when I run the code given in the example I get:

```
OSError: [WinError 740] The requested operation requires elevation
```

I am using Windows 10 and Jupyter Notebook in Pycharm. Any idea why I may be getting this error?

Expected to get the results shown in the "Example" part of readme file. But instead got an error.